# Is it safe to include connection data in token?

Tags: c#, web-api, oauth2

When generating a `ClaimIdentity` for use by oAuth in generating a token, is it safe to include database information as a claim?

My application uses a different database depending on the specific scenario (e.g. A demo user vs a live user).  I need the database connection details on every call in order to hit the correct database for the logged in user.

Is it safe to include this information as part of the identity that is used to generate the token? What is the likelihood that the token could be decrypted and the connection details extracted?

Comment: If you know what type of user they are when you auth them, why do you not just use the users DB to store the connection params that can change, and get them from there when you need them?

Comment: I need to know which database to connect to in the first instance.

Comment: How do you auth the user without knowing which DB to use?

Comment: There's a process in place which figures that out. By the time the auth process is complete, I know whether the user is authed, *and* relevant details about them, including the DB they should connect to.

Answer (score 2):

Typically with oAuth, the Realm field would be used for this purpose.  I could see you including a query string parameter which contains a key to point to a specific database connection or some other identifier which would allow you to know where a users data exists.

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617

> These realms allow the protected resources on a server to be partitioned into a set of protection spaces, each with its own authentication scheme and/or authorization database.

I would not store actual connection string details here though!  That type of data should never leave your application.  You should use a key, hash, or identifier and then use that to look up the connection string details internally.

Comment: +1 for "That type of data should never leave your application", with the added note that you should also never use such information when sent to you!